# Hook window messages

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can I hook windows messages for a particular window that gets created from my application. I've done this but I get an error saying `E2036 Variable required`.

```
type
  TSomeClass = class
  ...
  WndProc(code : integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM ) : LResult;
  ...
  end;

var
  SomeClass: TSomeClass;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  SomeClass := TSomeClass.Create;
  SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @SomeClass.WndProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: This happens because `@SomeClass.WndProc` is method pointer (look it up).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hook window messages for a window that you create, you can set the `WindowProc` property of the control that wraps the window. If that is possible then it is the right way to go.

Your call to `SetWindowHookEx` fails because you are not passing a hook procedure. You are passing an instance method. Your hook procedure must be a non-member function declared like this:

```
function HookProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM;
    lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
```

You must also adhere to the documented instructions. Remember the `HHOOK` instance that you are given by `SetWindowHookEx` and make sure you call `CallNextHookEx` to respect the hook chain.

Comment: Yes but what if i want to hook 5 different windows? Each belongs to a different class? In the end i just want to prevent focus stealing by these windows.

Comment: If you can use WindowProc do so. If you must use SetWindowHookEx, hook the thread and then deal with each window as you please. You'll hook every window proc call in the entire thread. Very hard for me to give specific advice for your app because I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I don't know what these windows are, who owns them and so on.

Comment: @user - Search for `MakeObjectInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to receive and process windows messages for any kind of window, not only such you created yourself, and be able to use your  member-function you can use my unit:

http://www.maxlogic.eu/subclassing-hooking-windows-with-delphi/

And here is how to use it:

```
    uses maxWndSubClassing;




TSomeClass = class
public
    WindowHook: TWndSubClass;
    procedure myWindowProc(var Msg: Messages.TMessage; var PrevendDefaultHandler: boolean);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  SomeClass := TSomeClass.Create;


  SomeClass.WindowHook := TWndSubClass.Create(nil);
  SomeClass.WindowHook.OnMessage := SomeClass.MyMessageProc;
  // this line assigns the window handle that will be hooked. Depending on what you are hooking, pass something else instead of aHandle
  SomeClass.WindowHook.HookedWnd := aHandle;
end;
```

Obviously, it would be better to put this code into the constructor of TSomeClass. 
Do not forget to release the SubClass using:

```
SomeClass.WindowHook.free;
```

Anyway I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this method as class member, you can use ***static;*** modifier with ***class function*** like this (D2006):

```
type
  TSomeClass = class
  ...
  class function WndProc(code : integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM ) : LResult; static; stdcall;
  ...
  end;

    var
      SomeClass: TSomeClass;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      ...
      SomeClass := TSomeClass.Create;
      SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @TSomeClass.WndProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId);
      ...
    end;
```

P.S. And don't remember stdcall; modifier for WinAPI func